# Integral of $\frac{\sin^2(x-y)}{(x-y)^2}$

Tags: calculus

Calculate the integral $$\int_{-t}^t\int_{-t}^t\frac{\sin^2(x-y)}{(x-y)^2}dxdy.$$ If we cannot get the exact value, does it equal to $2t-\frac{\log(2t)}{\pi^2}+O(1)$? Thank you!

Comment: The substitution $u = x-y, v = x+y$ should enable you to make this into a single integral. Maybe that's easier to evaluate, or at least see whether it actually is $\log(2t) + O(1)$.

Comment: It seems that the integral $\sim 4t^2$ when $t \to 0$.

Comment: $t$ should be a fixed positive number or even can be very large.

Comment: According to a paper, the result may be $2t-\frac{log(2t)}{\pi^2}+O(1).$

Answer (score 0):

Changing u=x-y we get $$\int \!{\frac { \left( \sin \left( x-y \right)  \right) ^{2}}{ \left(x-y \right) ^{2}}}\,{\rm d}y=\int \!-{\frac { \left( \sin \left( u
 \right)  \right) ^{2}}{{u}^{2}}}\,{\rm d}u$$
By parts, with f=sin(u):
$$1/2\,{u}^{-1}-1/2\,{\frac {\cos \left( 2\,u \right) }{u}}-{\it Si} \left( 2\,u \right) $$
Reverting the change, and given that integrating for dx is symmetric, so we have:
$$\int_{-t}^t\int_{-t}^t\frac{\sin^2(x-y)}{(x-y)^2}dxdy = 4\,{\it Si} \left( 4\,t \right) t+8\, \left( \cos \left( t \right) 
 \right) ^{4}-8\, \left( \cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2}-2\,\ln 
 \left( 2 \right) -\gamma+1/2\,{\it Ci} \left( -4\,t \right) -1/2\,
\ln  \left( -t \right) +1/2\,{\it Ci} \left( 4\,t \right) -1/2\,\ln 
 \left( t \right) 
$$

Comment: Parts explain: 

$$\int \!-{\frac { \left( \sin \left( u \right)  \right) ^{2}}{{u}^{2}}}
\,{\rm d}u={\frac { \left( \sin \left( u \right)  \right) ^{2}}{u}}-
\int \!2\,{\frac {\sin \left( u \right) \cos \left( u \right) }{u}}
\,{\rm d}u$$

and $$\int \!2\,{\frac {\sin \left( u \right) \cos \left( u \right) }{u}}
\,{\rm d}u={\it Si} \left( 2\,u \right) $$

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_{-t}^t\int_{-p}^p\frac{\sin^2(x-y)}{(x-y)^2}dxdy.$$

```
 (v= x-y) then upper limit is p-y and lower limit will be -p-y
```

If 2nd integral $p$ tends to infinity then

$$I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2(av)dv}{v^2}$$

$$=>\frac{dI}{da}=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(2av)dv}{v}=2\pi a$$

$$=>I(a)=\pi a^2+c$$

because $I(0)=0$ then c= 0

$$I(a)=\pi a^2$$

$=\int_{-t}^{t}\pi a^2 dy$

$= 2\pi a^2 t $; considered a=1

I tried my best level. I hope this will be some what help full

Comment: Alvaro brother once see your integral by parts [(sinu)/u]^2 . It's impossible to do integral by parts for this function.

Comment: If by parts is possible, pls explain me how ?